# Jquery UI Sortable drop and drag options (allowed and denied)

Tags: jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-sortable

Is it possible to do following scenario with http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#empty-lists framework:

```
Group 1        Group 2         Group 3
--------------------------------------
Item 1         Item 1          Item 1
Item 2         Item 2          Item 2
Item 3         Item 3          Item 3
```

I want to do this: I want to disable droppable action from Group 2 and Group 3 to Group 1, but allowed draggable and droppable action from Group 1 to Group 2 and Group 3 (it does not matter whether the Group 1 empty or not I want to denied from any other Groups to drag and drop items in to it, but from it to allow these action).

Is it possible to do it?

Comment: have you tried doing it ?

Comment: Yes, but I did't achieve anything.

Comment: Actually, I have some logic for this, and that logic is when you call update event, and when you drag and drop item from one group to another this event is call and you can return false on this event. But I like to know if this plugin has this feature.

Comment: I found out a solution: on **stop** event **return false.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I finished this with my own solution. My solution is on **stop** event I simply **return false**

Something like this:

```
$( ".sortable_element" ).sortable({
    stop: function(event, ui)
    {
        if(something can not be droppable)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```